# Clear / Erase TextBox Content With Button Click Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, triggers

I have the following XAML snippet:

```
<TextBox x:Name="FilterTB" TextChanged="FilterTB_TextChanged"/>
<Button x:Name="CancelFilterSelectionButton" FontWeight="Bold" Content="X"/>
```

I'd like to erase the content of the TextBox when the user presses the Button.

Of course doing so from Code Behind is a trivial task, but I wanted to accomplish it only through the use of XAML, and so using Triggers.

I tried researching on the net, but I either found uncorrect solutions, or overly-convoluted solutions, so I'd like to hear some clean and compact solutions.

Comment: I think you need `Command` instead of trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I had a spare minute, hope this helps, cheers.

namespaces;

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

and easy peasy.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center">

   <TextBox x:Name="ThatThangToClear" Width="250"/>

   <Button x:Name="ClearThatThang" Content="Clear That Thang" Margin="5,0">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
               <ei:ChangePropertyAction 
                   TargetName="ThatThangToClear" 
                   TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ThatThangToClear}"
                   PropertyName="Text" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>           
   </Button>

</StackPanel>
```

Oh, and P.S. - You really only need either `TargetName` OR `TargetObject` but I included both for examples sake.