# TextBox delete button (the little x) not visible when Text set through binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I have a UWP app (C#) with a `TextBox`. The textbox is bound to a property, two way:

```
Text="{Binding NameFilterString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

When I type into the `TextBox` the "delete button" - the little x in the right corner - appears. Clicking on it clears the `TextBox`'s Text and the Property value, as expected.

When the property changes the `TextBox'`s Text is correctly updated, but the delete button doesn't appear. Can I somehow make it visible? Either by a property or by somehow "refreshing" it?

Comment: Its Visibility is controlled via the [ButtonVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx) state in the VSM of the Style template. You could do a `VisualStateManager.GoToState` method, or you could just go edit the template so it's always visible. Or Template bind that property and toggle it that way. Wish I had time to throw together an example, but do not, so just left as comment.

Comment: Ok I now see that this is a focus problem, not a binding problem. The x is visible when the textbox has focus, and in the scenario I was looking for the x the TextBox no longer had focus... I would still love an example of how to always show it, or how to control the visibility yourself.

Comment: Oh that would be really easy. If you go look at the default template see how they have `Visibility="Collapsed"` set explicitly on `DeleteButton`? So you could just del that and the VisualState for that matter. Or Template bind it (I usually piggy back in on the `Tag` property since it's there for that sort of thing and then you don't have to create a dependency property). Easy peasy. Or you could be creative and just do it yourself with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081106/clear-erase-textbox-content-with-button-click-event).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so well versed in XAML and templates, I could really do with an example. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I've actually got a little time today. You just want to know where/how to go remove the explicitly set visibility=collapsed? Or how to templatebind that property to hit it from the instance level? Or something else?

Comment: An example of how to expose the visibility as a property would be perfect. Somwthing that I can access from the code behind. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just right-click your TextBox -> Edit Template -> Edit a copy. Below is just a default I took from the docs for example with comments next to what you would change.

```
            <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox -->
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <!-- *** We add a setter for a default -->
              <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Collapsed"/>
              <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
              <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}" />
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
              <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
              <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
              <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
              <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
              <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
              <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>
                      <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                          <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}"
                                                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                                Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                      <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                      <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                      </VisualState>
                                      <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                                          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                      </VisualState>
                                      <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                           To="0"
                                                           Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                      </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                  <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                              Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackMediumBrush}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              FontStyle="Normal"
                                              FontSize="12"
                                              Text="&#xE10A;"
                                              FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                </Grid>
                              </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                          </Setter>
                        </Style>
                      </Grid.Resources>
                      <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                          <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                          <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                          <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightChromeAltLowBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundHoverOpacity}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                          <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                            <Storyboard>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextChromeBlackMediumLowBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocusedOpacity}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackHighBrush}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">    
                          <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
<!-- *** We need to ditch this default VisualState, so take what exists and swap it for this.
                            <Storyboard>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                  </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
    -->
                          </VisualState>
                          <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                      </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Opacity="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundRestOpacity}"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                              Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                      <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                              Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                      <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                        x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                                        Margin="0,0,0,8"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                        FontWeight="Normal" />
                      <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                    VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                    IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                    IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                    IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                    ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                      <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        <!-- *** Here's your culprit, notice the change to the value -->
                      <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                              IsTabStop="False"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Visibility="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                              FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                              MinWidth="34"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                  </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Then at the instance;

```
<TextBox Tag="{Binding blah}"/>
```

If you're setting a bool, don't forget to add a Visibility converter on it. Voila, done. Hope this helps.

OH PS - Also don't forget to add `Style="{StaticResource TheCopiedTemplateNameYouMade}"` to it if you're not using the default to reference the edited style for inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for this. This works as far as visibility is concerned, but now I have another problem... Now, when I click on the delete button when the control doesn't have focus, when the button would normally not be visible (but now is) the clear action is not executed. So the animation of the pressing of the "x" happens, but text box text is not cleared. Any tips?

Comment: To fix that I've added a Click event handler in the template, that just calls textbox.Focus. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Might just have taken adding `ClickMode=Press` to the button, that's a common one, but glad you found a remedy!