# XAML-only clear combobox on button click

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, combobox, triggers

I'd like to clear the combobox selection/content on button click, all in XAML, no code. Am I using the storyboard correctly? Do I need a storyboard at all?

I'm inside an ItemsControl, so it's not easy and quite ugly to go through the visual tree.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock FontSize="20" 
               Text="Sensitivity Parameter: "  
               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbSensitivityParameter2" 
              FontSize="20" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource parameter2SensitivityNameListConverter}" 
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                         Mode="OneWay">
                <Binding ElementName="tbUserLevel" 
                         Path="IsChecked"/>
                <Binding Path="Parameters"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" 
            Width="50" 
            Height="50" 
            Margin="10,0,0,0" 
            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=cbSensitivityParameter2, Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource hideMeConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" 
                             Visual="{StaticResource appbar_delete}" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <SingleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="cbSensitivityParameter2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="SelectedIndex">
                            <LinearSingleKeyFrame Value="-1" />
                        </SingleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd think you could just do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081106/clear-erase-textbox-content-with-button-click-event) but hit the `SelectedItem` property instead of Text like in the example.

Comment: Great. Put it as an answer so I can mark it and give you the credit...